Interaction-free measurement and energy and momentum transfer
I was reading an article by Lev Vaidman, who helped create the quantum bomb tester thought experiment which inspired much work on quantum interaction-free measurements (IFMs), that was analyzing the exact meaning of interaction pertaining to IFMs. I am a little cautious to accept his exact words on the matter since he is proudly convinced of the many-worlds interpretation and, although I have no problems with people subscribing to any interpretation, I want to know that I'm learning from an unbiased source. In this article, Vaidman claims that quantum IFMs as produced in Kwiat et al. are interaction-free in the sense that a photon or other quantum object is not located at the location of the measured object, but not in the sense that there is no exchange of energy or momentum. How can this be? How interaction-free are quantum IFMs? I know many of the specifications rely on one's interpretation, but I just want to know if the quantum is located at the site of the measured object and if there is an energy exchange between the measured object and the quantum that "measures" it and, if so, how.

Possibly related: (1) , (2)
